# How can I combine these two arrays into a single 3d array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d, collision

I have a functioning start to a text-based game and in it are two arrays the main array called mainArray which contains the info to display a bordered map, and a collision array called colArray which contains the info to stop the player from walking off the map.

It is currently functioning as intended except for one problem. I want to store the collision information in the mainArray as a 3d array instead of 2d but every attempt I have tried to work with it has failed.

I keep thinking it should be as simple as adding to the if statements in the initMap function a third [] next to mainArray[i][j] something like mainArray[i][j][k] and then store the "solid" strings there but this doesn't work.

[Here is a link to a diffrent version where I am trying to implement the third dimension and test for it without running any checks for "solid" and am instead just testing for k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60441993/javascript-why-is-the-alert-saying-undefined-and-not-the-letter-k)

And below is the working code of the game using 2d arrays mainArray and colArray which I would like to combine into one 3d array. you can run the code here as well. You may need to click fullscreen after running the code to see what is happening.

```js
function gameloop() {
  var mainArray = [];
  var colArray = [];
  var mapSizeX = 32;
  var mapSizeY = 128;
  var idPos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  function initMap(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
      mainArray.push([])
      colArray.push([])

      for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
        mainArray[i][j] = ".";
        colArray[i][j] = "";

        if (j == 0) {
          mainArray[i][j] = "#";
          colArray[i][j] = "Solid";
        }
        if (j == mapSizeY - 1) {
          mainArray[i][j] = "#";
          colArray[i][j] = "Solid";
        }
        if (i == 0) {
          mainArray[i][j] = "#";
          colArray[i][j] = "Solid";
        }
        if (i == mapSizeX - 1) {
          mainArray[i][j] = "#";
          colArray[i][j] = "Solid";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function nl() {
    GameScreen.innerText += "\n";
  }

  function render() {
    GameScreen.innerText = mainArray.map(arr => arr.join("")).join("\n");
    nl();
    nl();
  }

  function reposition(xChange, yChange, strA) {
    if (colArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange] === "Solid") {
      GameLog.innerText = "You can not travel in that direction"
    } else {
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y] = ".";
      idPos.x = idPos.x + xChange;
      idPos.y = idPos.y + yChange;
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y] = "@";
      GameLog.innerText = "You take a step to the " + strA
    }

    render();
  }

  //Startup
  initMap(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY);
  idPos.x = mapSizeX / 2;
  idPos.y = mapSizeY / 2;
  mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y] = "@";
  //First Render
  render();

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      reposition(-1, 0, "North");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      reposition(1, 0, "South");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      reposition(0, -1, "West");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      reposition(0, 1, "East");
    }
    //alert(event.keyCode);
  });
}

gameloop();
```

```html
<p style="color:#7d7d7d;font-family:Lucida Console;">Dungeon Valley.<br>
  <font style="color:#ABABAB;font-family:Lucida Console;font-size:0.5em" ;>
    Taming the Borderlands.<br> v0.005 By heromedel. </P>
</font>
<P>
  <section id="GameScreen" style="color:#000000;font-family:Lucida Console;"></section>
  <P>
    <section id="GameLog" style="color:#000000;font-family:Lucida Console;">Arrow Keys to move.<br></section>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not related to your problem: Your HTML contains some improperly nested or unclosed tags. Please check the tags' capitalization, nesting etc.

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks for cleaning up the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `mainArray[x][y]` is an string. If you want to store additional properties at that (coordinate) level, you need to replace that string with an object containing the properties.

I've updated your code to do so.

Some notes:

- I replaced your 4 wall `if` statements with a single `if` checking all 4 conditions.
- In the `render` function, a extra `map` had to be added to extract the surface symbol from the new object.
- All references to `mainArray[x][y]` were updated to `mainArray[x][y].surface`.

```js
function gameloop() {
  var mainArray = [];
  var colArray = [];
  var mapSizeX = 32;
  var mapSizeY = 128;
  var idPos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  function initMap(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mapSizeX; i++) {
      mainArray.push([])
      colArray.push([])

      for (var j = 0; j < mapSizeY; j++) {
        mainArray[i][j] = {
          surface: "."
        };
        colArray[i][j] = "";

        if (j == 0 ||
          j == mapSizeY - 1 ||
          i == 0 ||
          i == mapSizeX - 1) {
          mainArray[i][j].surface = "#";
          colArray[i][j] = "Solid";
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function nl() {
    GameScreen.innerText += "\n";
  }

  function render() {
    GameScreen.innerText = mainArray.map(arr => arr.map(cell => cell.surface).join("")).join("\n");
    nl();
    nl();
  }

  function reposition(xChange, yChange, strA) {
    if (colArray[idPos.x + xChange][idPos.y + yChange] === "Solid") {
      GameLog.innerText = "You can not travel in that direction"
    } else {
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].surface = ".";
      idPos.x = idPos.x + xChange;
      idPos.y = idPos.y + yChange;
      mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].surface = "@";
      GameLog.innerText = "You take a step to the " + strA
    }

    render();
  }

  //Startup
  initMap(mainArray, mapSizeX, mapSizeY);
  idPos.x = mapSizeX / 2;
  idPos.y = mapSizeY / 2;
  mainArray[idPos.x][idPos.y].surface = "@";
  //First Render
  render();

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      reposition(-1, 0, "North");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      reposition(1, 0, "South");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 37) {
      reposition(0, -1, "West");
    }
    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
      reposition(0, 1, "East");
    }
    //alert(event.keyCode);
  });
}

gameloop();
```

```css
.info {
  color: #7d7d7d;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
}

.info span {
  color: #ABABAB;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
  font-size: 0.5em;
}

#GameScreen,
#GameLog {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Lucida Console;
}
```

```html
<p class="info">Dungeon Valley.<br>
  <span class="">
    Taming the Borderlands.<br> v0.005 By heromedel.
  </span>
</p>
<section id="GameScreen"></section>
<section id="GameLog">Arrow Keys to move.<br></section>
```

Comment: The way that you added .surface allowed me to add another I called .solid and then tested if true. This allowed me to completely remove the colArray from my code and still keep the walls # solid which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Also, I don't yet understand how .map works someone else helped me come up with that line so thank you for updating the code so that it is working with .surface.

I also noticed that you made me a css style sheet. So I have incorporated that into my code and files as well.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You’re very welcome! Thanks for accepting my answer :-) `.map` is used to map an array to something else. The function you pass to `.map` is called for every item, and the return value of that function is what is added instead of that item. Try this: `[1, 2, 3].map(item => item * 2)`

Comment: `item => item * 2` is shorthand for `function (item) { return item * 2; }`